# Experience Optimization: Page Preview is not coming in

Tags: experience-optimization

I am facing a very weird case with Experience Optimization in Sitecore 9.1.1 described below:

1. I logged-in to Sitecore as admin
2. Went to Experience Optimization
3. Created a new page test
4. Selected a page item
5. After selecting it I can see below screen with blank preview

[image]

This same page test is working in Sitecore 8.2 Version. So don't know exactly what is the issue here.

Comment: are you getting any error in the console and what is value of `ContentTesting.GenerateScreenshots` setting?

Comment: No errors in Console and I have below
<setting name="ContentTesting.GenerateScreenshots" value="all" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.config"/>

Comment: I found a below log but don't know how to resolve this in Azure app service looks like phantonjs.exe don't have permissions 

18280 15:26:43 INFO  [Content Testing]: PhantomJS console: 
Resource error
id: 1
url: https://mycmdomain/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7B2D71DB62-0DD6-4668-A83A-C776909C8834%7D&sc_disable_edit=yes&sc_lang=en&sc_version=41&sc_vercomp=0
errorCode: 99
errorString: Unable to write
!--error--!

Comment: Could you share more logs? or what the console displays? This looks more like a Javascript issue.